# Java Inheritance of Stack

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extend

I'm trying to extend the stack class, but I was wondering if I were to do this:

```
class test extends Stack<Integer> 
{
    public boolean add(Integer i)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            super.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Would that code also change it so using test.push() would also use the above code?
EDIT: Also, if I don't define a specific constructor, does it call the parent's default constructor?

Comment: `Int` ? is it custom defined type or u meant `Integer` ?

Comment: Yeah sorry that's what I meant... too used to C++

Comment: I don't think you can specify the generic type when you're extending a class like Stack.  You'll need to use something like `class test extends Stack<T>`

Comment: So even if I want to only make it so this stack works with Integers?

Answer (score 1):

> Would that code also change it so using test.push() would also use the
>   above code?

I don't think so because I don't think the `push` method in `java.util.Stack` calls the `add` method.  The `push` method looks like this:

```
    public E push(E item) {
        addElement(item);

        return item;
    }
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

To answer the second question...

> Also, if I don't define a specific constructor, does it call the
>   parent's default constructor?

If you do not declare a constructor then you get a default no argument constructor which invokes the default no argument constructor in the parent class.  The following are the same with respect to this...

```
public class One extends Stack {
}

public class Two extends Stack {
    public Two() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a terrible idea to do that. Although add method seems not to be used by Stack class (addElement is used) it has several problems:

- Add method is not part of the expected stack API, is part of the internal representation (used or not used by the class)
- You will end up with different ways of adding elements, through add, excluding zeroes, and through push, including zeroes.
- Invoking add method with zero gives no error, so, a user would think that the stack contains the element.

Are you trying to have a Stack that does not accept zero elements? Perhaps composition would be a better solution for that...